# preg_replace for a word ending with a colon

Tags: php

I've tried looking into preg_replace, except that I have not much experience with regular expressions.

What I'm trying to do is replace a portion of text ending with a colon and make it bold and put a line break in before and 2 line breaks after.

IE convert this text

```
title1: is some text here. title2: another piece of text.
```

to

```
**title1:**
is some text here.

**title2:**
another piece of text
```

I've tried doing something like this...

```
preg_replace("!\*(.*?)\*!$:","\<br \/\>\<strong\>!\*(.*?)\*!\<\/strong\>\<br \/\>",$text);
```

I can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Andi

Comment: Will all of your text always look like that? ie: title: body. title:body. title:body.

Comment: Do you know if the problem is in the replacement or the pattern?

Comment: No its a text field in a database. I want to take any text like this ---> Permitting: Forest land clearance for the project is currently blah blah blah. Contracts: Civil contract with Coastal Projectsblah blah blah..... and split the text into something more readable...

Comment: are the title and the text in one text field in the database or are they separate?  If they are separate you should format them before making one string of them.  I'm working on the correct regexs now in case they are one.

Comment: They can add any text and headings. Can't use an HTML WYSIWYG as I have a rather strange issue with the server at the moment.

Comment: ...but there is always a fullstop at the end of a statement? And only at the end?

Comment: Let's really throw a wrench in it.  What if the text was "This is my title: I like periods.  I really really really like them.  I type alot of periods.... ... Sometimes I type colons too : : : .. . This is title number 2: lkjhasfdlhkjasfd"  I assume there is some limitation on the fields (like not allowing :'s or only allowing one . per body).  They should have thought through their DB a bit more.

Comment: LoL no the comments is a relational table (portfolio -> comments) - Its a single text field. There's a date and a a userID to log who made the comment and when, however the HTML editor isn't working correctly so I've got to have another work around if the put a lot of text in the comments. I do not know how many titles they will have or if these will change or I would have created drop downs with a many to many relationship (an intermediate table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`preg_replace` regexes need to be delimited. So, first, try encasing your regex in slashes. Second, I don't understand your regex. Something simple like `/(\w+):/` should work.

```
preg_replace("/(\w+):/", "<br><br><b>$1</b><br>", $text);
```

@AndiLeeDavis Edited answer to handle multi-word titles and get rid of extraneous breaks at the beginning:

```
$mtext = preg_replace("/\.?\s*([^\.]+):/", "<br><br><b>$1</b><br>", $text);
if (strcmp(substr($mtext, 0, 8), "<br><br>") == 0) $mtext = substr($mtext, 8);
```

Comment: @Ansari I actually learned everything I know about regex patterns just now.  Do you know if either of our choices are 'better' or if its just a personal preference?

Comment: the "portion of text ending with a colon" is always just one word? Duh

Comment: Nice and simple, but the problem with this is it inserts two line breaks prior to the first line.  Doubt op wants that.

Comment: if op doesn't want that he can do preg_replace("^<br>", "", $str) or $str = substr($str,4).  However, all of our solutions so far do assume title will always be one word.

Comment: @Jake No. The answer should be complete.  No need for a second regex here.

Comment: No sometimes there is two words.

Comment: @madbreaks agreed.  I was just posting a quick and dirty work around for our shortcomings.

Comment: @Jake it's a personal preference I guess. You don't really need to check for whitespace before the part you're interested in (it HAS to be whitespace). Madbreaks: Yes I realize it inserts two extraneous lines - it depends on what OP wants exactly and how sensitive he/she is to extra whitespace. I just wanted to keep it simple is all. If there is more than one word, you'll need a slightly more complicated regex to get the part after the last period.

Comment: My decision is to keep the regex as simple as possible and separately handle the side effect of two line breaks at the beginning. Anyway, the second bit of code handles multi-word titles as well.

Comment: Hmmm. It certainly removed the erroneous line breaks at the start. But it didn't work on this text... Permitting:
Forest land blah blah Q2 2012.

Contracts:
Civil contract blah blah. -->Debt (this is supposed to be part of the title

Financing:
blah blah....

Comment: Hahaha of course not! I'm just an amateur user of regexes. Anyway, it's really weird - the error happens inside preg_replace, which throws a backtrack limit reached error. Which doesn't make sense because the string is relatively tiny. Digging further ...

Comment: @AndiLeeDavis Phew OK I edited the answer again - I guess the nested expressions were causing [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Anyway, it should work now.

Comment: @Ansari This is the one!!!!! Thanks sooooo much. I never get to grips with Regular expressions. You are a star.

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = 'title1: is some text here. title2: another piece of text.';

echo preg_replace('#(\w+:) (.+?\.) ?#', "<b>$1</b><br />$2<br /><br />", $text);
```

...gives:

```
<b>title1:</b><br />is some text here.<br /><br /><b>title2:</b><br />another piece of text.<br /><br />
```

Cheers

Comment: ok I got an error on that last one but this one works fine. Thanks so much guys...  preg_replace("/(\w+):/","<br /><br /><strong>$1</strong><br />",$row_publish_comment['comment']);

Comment: @AndiLeeDavis I fixed the RegEx, and you're welcome.  If it was helpful, please consider up-voting the answer (if you can).  thanks.

Comment: @madbreaks I like it!  Gratz on figuring it out.

Comment: Won't this only grab the first sentence after the colon though?

Comment: Yeah it does. I'm trying to see if I can modify what you show me to look out for more than one word titles.

Comment: @AndiLeeDavis Edited my answer to handle multi-word titles.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $str = 'title1: is some text here. title2: another piece of text.';
   $str = preg_replace("/(\w+:)/", "\n\n**$1**\n", $str);
   echo $str;
```